# How do I Regex website URLs for apache nutch?

Tags: regex, url, nutch

I am trying to set up apache nutch to crawl only websites with a specified domain using Regex. I don't have much experience with Regex and I'm having trouble working out how to do my domain in Regex. 
The domain is
`https://www.health.gov.au/`
and I would like any web page with this domain followed by anything else to be accepted by the Regex.
thanks for your time

EDIT
for example, I would like `https://www.health.gov.au/health-topics` to be accepted by the Regex

Comment: What seems to be a problem?

Comment: I don't know the syntax to allow any webpages with the domain in the url to be allowed. e.g. I would like ```https://www.health.gov.au/health-topics``` to be allowed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `(https://www.health.gov.au/.*)`.

This will match all characters after  `https://www.health.gov.au/`

[RegexDemo](https://regex101.com/r/2w3NYX/1)